# PHP - fgetcsv() reset pointer

Tags: php, fgetcsv

How do I reset the file pointer with fgetcsv()?

I have the loop below, nested inside another while loop. However it starts reading the CSV from the break point rather than the beginning after first run.

```
while($line2 = fgetcsv($fp2, $length2, $fildDelineate2)) {
        if($line[0] == $line2[0]) {
            $desc = addslashes(strip_tags($line2[6]));
            $import2 = "insert into $table2 values('$id','1',\"$line[1]\",'$desc','','0')";
            mysql_query($import2) or die('import2 '.mysql_error());
            $count++;
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Over two years later I Google a coding problem. Click on the top result. It's my own question. :-|

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [rewind()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) or [fseek()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to do this:

```
rewind($fp2);
// ...is the same as:
fseek($fp2, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`rewind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php)

Answer (score 1):

Continue is the best solution .... try this

```
 continue 2 ;
```